# Intellij reformatter remove indent of empty lines

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I have search widely but cannot find my answer. The place I work use eclipse for Java with a customize formatter, this formatter keep indent (a tab) for empty lines. However, in in intellij, the reformatter remove the tab which cause a gigantic modification of the code when use git diff. So I am wondering if there is any way to keep the indent when doing auto reformatting? I knew I can keep those when saving a file but not sure if it can be done when using reformatter.

Comment: Actually I didn't try but maybe this can be helpful. https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days trials, finally found it. Intellij can be enforced to keep indent on empty lines. See attached [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpvTN.png)